# How can I connect to my SQL Database through C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, database-connection

I've seen some similar questions but most are based around PHP, there was one based around C but the only answer was go to the **SQLConnect()** docs, which I've already done.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconnect-function?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Seems to be little content online, also I'm a beginner so excuse any silly issues. 
I set up the SQL database using the MYSQL Workbench and it's sitting on my localhost:3306. I was able to connect it to the ODBC Data Source Admin program successfully.

So I believe I'm using the right function and have the right SQL back end set up, I just don't know where to go from here.

The end goal is to be able to 'insert' records into my database with the program and also 'select' from it too.

**What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?**

```
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <sql.h>
    # include <sqlext.h>
    # include <cstdio>
    # include <cstdint>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        SQLHENV henv = NULL;
        SQLHDBC hdbc = NULL;

        /* Initialize the ODBC environment handle. */
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, NULL, &henv);

        /* Set the ODBC version to version 3 (the highest version) */
        SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
            (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

        /* Allocate the connection handle. */
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);

        SQLConnectW(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR*)"localhost", (SQLSMALLINT) 9, 
                    (SQLWCHAR*)"root", (SQLSMALLINT)4, 
                    (SQLWCHAR*)"password", (SQLSMALLINT)8);

        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Mesa no SQL jedi, but `(SQLWCHAR*)"localhost"` looks off. `"localhost"` is a going to provide an array of `char` and the W in `SQLWCHAR` looks a whole lot like `SQLWCHAR` wants wide chars.

Comment: There are many examples on the internet of how to connect to the MySQL database.  You should search for "c++ mysql connect".

Comment: The is this tutorial, where you should start http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.4/en/connector-cpp-getting-started-examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the comments inside the code, which will help you to understand the code easily.
Credits: [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html)

```
/* Includes Standard C++  */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/

#include "mysql_connection.h" 
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Successfull' »
           AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Successfull' AS _message"); // replace with your statement
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting the following errors when building...
```1>accessSQL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main```
I've tried adding dlls to my debug folder, I don't know whats going wrong..

Comment: UPDATE: This was an error with not including .lib files that come in the SQL Connector 8.0 C ++ download. I used this code to include each of the lib files ```#pragma comment(lib, "path/libfilename.lib")```